# What's the easiest way to list files of a given extension, save that list to a text file, but omitting the actual extensions when in the text file?

Tags: bash, find, grep

This is for a counterstrike server, where mapcycle.txt contains all the maps found in the maps/ folder, but the list of maps must not contain the .bsp extension.

Example of maps/ folder:

```
map1.bsp
map2.bsp
```

mapcycle.txt should contain

```
map1
maps2
```

I am aware of how to do part of it:

```
find /path/to/maps/ -iname *.bsp > /path/to/mapcycle.txt
```

But I don't know how to have it omit the .bsp extensions inside the actual mapcycle.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/find.1.html) and [`basename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/basename.1.html):

```
find maps/ -iname '*.bsp' -exec basename {} .bsp \; > mapcycle.txt
```

The `-exec` flag runs the rest of the command line (until a `;` or `+` is encountered) replacing `{}` with the the filename of a selected file (including the path). `basename /path/to/filename.suffix .suffix` will strip out the suffix and the path and leave only `filename`.

Comment: This is beautiful. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

It will be:

> ls *.bsp | awk -F"." '{print $1}' > mapcycle.txt

Comment: This will omit dot file by default.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: The `dotglob` shell option is off by default in `bash`. So if there is a file like `.map1.bsp`, this will omit it.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd  to map folder
```

and execute

```
ls *.bsp |sed s/\.[^\.]*$// >> list.txt
```

Comment: This will omit dot files by default.